# how to adjust font size according to the paragraph element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph element which is looking like this[image]

It works fine when there are 3 digit characters, but it somehow overflows from the div element. Can anyone suggest a way to auto adjust the font size according to the paragraph element?

the code for this div is this

```
<div class="details">
            <a><span
                    style="display: block;line-height: 22px;padding-top: 20px;"><b>8375</b></span>
                <span style="display: block;font-size: 17px;padding-top: 5px;">posts</span></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```
$(".text").css("font-size", $("#details").height()/4);
```

Css

```
<style>
    #details {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background:red;
        border:1px solid green;
        }
</style>
```

Html

```
<div id="details">
<a>
    <span class="text"><b>8375</b></span>
    <span class="text">posts</span>
</a>
```

Now if your font size will be resized according block height :)

Comment: this doesnt work when you put in more numbers like 3333333333333

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="details" style="width:auto;">
```